# get_source_inputs function in keras

Tags: python, function, deep-learning, keras

What is the purpose of get_source_inputs() function in keras. I dont see any information about this in the documentation.

```
from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py):

`def get_source_inputs(tensor, layer=None, node_index=None):`

> Returns the list of input tensors necessary to compute `tensor`.
>
> Output will always be a list of tensors  (potentially with 1 element).
>
> **Arguments**
>
> tensor: The tensor to start from.
>
> layer: Origin layer of the tensor. Will be determined via tensor._keras_history if not provided.
>
> node_index: Origin node index of the tensor.
>
> **Returns**
>           List of input tensors.